# align multiple lines across vertical limit without table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tablecell

I build a ecommerce website and have multiple p tag that describe the product.
I want that the product description will be align according to vertical line no matter the size of the word that precedes it. I want to know if this is possible to achieve this using perhaps flexbox or something like that but not table.

What I have now using gap and flexbox:

[image: This is what I get]

Code:

```
p
{
    display:flex;
    gap: 50px;
}
<p><span> Material:</span> <span > 18k Gold Plating</span></p>
<p><span> One:</span> <span > 18k Plating</span></p>
<p><span> Twotwo:</span> <span > 18k Yellow Plating</span></p>
<p><span> threethree:</span> <span > 18k Gold Plating</span></p>
<p><span> Four:</span> <span > 18k Gold</span></p>
```

What I want:

[image: Good one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method, in browsers that don't support `grid-template-columns: subgrid` would be to wrap the elements in a container – in the following code I used a `<main>` element – with `display: grid` and with the `<p>` elements set to `display: contents`, which effectively pretends that the `<p>` elements aren't there, or are "invisible" to the DOM and layout:

```css
*, ::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: system-ui;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 80vw, 1000px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  
  /* implementing grid display on the <main> element: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting the gap between adjacent rows to 0.5em and
     between adjacent columns to 1em: */
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  /* setting the width of the first column to "min-content"
     to have the column take the smallest necessary width,
     and the second column can take the remaining space: */
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}

p {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p><span>Material:</span><span>18k Gold Plating</span></p>
  <p><span>One:</span><span>18k Plating</span></p>
  <p><span>Twotwo:</span><span>18k Yellow Plating</span></p>
  <p><span>threethree:</span><span>18k Gold Plating</span></p>
  <p><span>Four:</span><span>18k Gold</span></p>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/68v237fh/).

References:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).

Answer (score 1):

You can add fixed width to the first span of every p element, in px or % to start 2nd span from the same spot.

```
p span:first-child {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

or you can also use table css properties without using table html like this.

```
p {
    display: table-row;
}
p span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Flexbox, an elegant way to do it would be to have 2 different **div**s for your columns, with *justify-content: flex-start* applied to it. You can also play with the column width if it's needed:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <p>Material:</p>
      <p>Beads:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p>18k Gold Plating</p>
      <p>2 Charms</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  justify-content: flex-start; /* or space-around, depending on if you want even space around them */
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on considering you will not change your existing html (which is not very cool at all xD)
Lets use css grid

```css
p
{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p><span> Material:</span> <span > 18k Gold Plating</span></p>
<p><span> One:</span> <span > 18k Plating</span></p>
<p><span> Two:</span> <span > 18k Yellow Plating</span></p>
<p><span> Three:</span> <span > 18k Gold Plating</span></p>
<p><span> Four:</span> <span > 18k Gold</span></p>
```